# Two tables of contents, the second one with selected sections

Tags: table-of-contents

I have structured my thesis in a way that by reading some selected sections, one can have a complete and fast(er) review of it. I have my normal table of contents (example 1) but I would like to add an additional "Table of contents fast track" so to say (example 2), showing only the sections which need to be read for the review.

I know how to show only one ToC with selected sections by using `\chapter*{}` or `\section*{}` in the chapters or sections I don't want to show. Is there an (uncomplicated) way to have both ToCs?

In addition, in the ToC "fast track" I would like to show the "real" section numbers, those that each section has in example 1.

Example 1: Normal table of contents

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter1} 
\section{Section1.1} % Fast track
\section{Section1.2} % Fast track
\section{Section1.3} % Fast track

\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}
\section{Section2.2}
\section{Section2.3} % Fast track

\chapter{Chapter3}
\section{Section3.1}
\section{Section3.2} % Fast track
\section{Section3.3}

\end{document}
```

Table of contents "fast track"

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Fast track contents}
\tableofcontents 

\chapter*{Chapter1}  
\section{Section1.1} % Fast track 
\section{Section1.2} % Fast track 
\section{Section1.3} % Fast track

\chapter*{Chapter2} 
\section*{Section2.1} 
\section*{Section2.2} 
\section{Section2.3} % Fast track

\chapter*{Chapter3} 
\section*{Section3.1} 
\section{Section3.2} % Fast track 
\section*{Section3.3}

\end{document}
```

[image: I would like the ToC "fast track" showing "real" section numbers]

### Thanks.

Edit: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549351/format-of-fast-track-contents-additional-table-of-contents) I asked a further question about how to format the "fast track ToC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tocloft package to define a new list of contents.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlistof[chapter]{fasttrack}{ftk}{Fast track contents} % Define the list of fast... 

\newcommand{\fasttracksection}[1]{% This is the special section 
  \section{#1}
  \addcontentsline{ftk}{fasttrack}{\protect\numberline{\thefasttrack}#1}}
\renewcommand{\thefasttrack}{} % No section numbers 

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \listoffasttrack

  \chapter{Chapter1} 
    \fasttracksection{Section1.1} % Fast track
    \fasttracksection{Section1.2} % Fast track
    \fasttracksection{Section1.3} % Fast track

  \chapter{Chapter2}
    \section{Section2.1}
    \section{Section2.2}
    \fasttracksection{Section2.3} % Fast track

  \chapter{Chapter3}
    \section{Section3.1}
    \fasttracksection{Section3.2} % Fast track
    \section{Section3.3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Would it be easy that the "fast track" ToC has the actual section numbers (2.3, etc)? (it it is not easy, don't spend any time in this!) I don't really understand the code yet, but I tried adding 'stuff' inside the `{}` of `\renewcommand{\thefasttrack}{}` to see what it does and I suspect that if I introduce the "table of contents counter" there, I would get what I want. Is it so? What is the name of this counter? I tried `\refstepcounter` and other things and didn't work...

Comment: Oh, I found the name! XD `\thesection`! However, the numbers are very close to the section names. I tried placing `\quad` in different places but I don't manage to separate the section numbers from the section names. How should I do it?

Comment: I found it, sorry. The `\quad` has to be placed before `#1`: `\addcontentsline{ftk}{fasttrack}{\protect\numberline{\thefasttrack}\quad #1}}`. Should I delete the comments or leave them for others to know how to tweak this?

Comment: As you like. But add comments to your code is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a slight edit to your MWE

```
% quicktocprob.tex  SE 544913
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}  % PW added

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Fast track contents}
\tableofcontents 

\chapter*{Chapter1}  
\section{Section1.1} % Fast track 
\section{Section1.2} % Fast track 
\section{Section1.3} % Fast track

\chapter*{Chapter2} 
\section*{Section2.1} 
\section*{Section2.2} 
\section{Section2.3} % Fast track

\chapter*{Chapter3} 
\section*{Section3.1} 
\section{Section3.2} % Fast track 
\section*{Section3.3}

\end{document}
```

The `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` only numbers chapters and above, so sections are unnumbered which is what you wanted in your Fast Track Contents. It may not be what you want in the body, though.

But now you ask for both ToCs within the code for one document. Here is a revision of your main MWE that does that.

```
% twotocprob.tex SE 544913
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Fast track contents}
\tableofcontents
\input{quicktocprob.toc}

\chapter{Chapter1} 
\section{Section1.1} % Fast track
\section{Section1.2} % Fast track
\section{Section1.3} % Fast track

\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}
\section{Section2.2}
\section{Section2.3} % Fast track

\chapter{Chapter3}
\section{Section3.1}
\section{Section3.2} % Fast track
\section{Section3.3}

\end{document}
```

You first have to run the `quicktocprob` code then the `twotocprob` code. I do not know how you want your final document to look like.

Comment: Thank. And how can I have both ToC at the same time?

Comment: To restore the deeper listing, increase the value of the `secnumdepth` counter and repeat the `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Apologies, Peter!  I really meant `\setcounter{tocdepth}`; same values apply as for as `secnumdepth`.